# How to generate data similar to a fitted generalized additive model?

Tags: generalized-additive-model

I need some hint for how we can simulate data similar to a fitted generalized additive model. In case of a linear regression model for example, consider the regression model below is fitted to a set of data with n observations:

$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1i} + \cdots + \beta_mx_{mi}+\epsilon_i \quad ; \quad i=1,\cdots,n
$$

with each $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma)$. Then the parameters estimates, say $\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta}_1,\cdots,\hat{\beta}_m$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ are found. Now similar data to this model in a certain point $\textbf{x}=(x_1,\cdots , x_m)$ is generated as follows. A random number from a normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}$ is generated and is added to $\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta_1}x_{1} + \cdots + \hat{\beta_m}x_{m}$.

Now consider the generalized additive model:
$$
y_i=f_1(x_{i1})+\cdots+f_m(x_{im})+\epsilon_i \quad ; \quad i=1,\cdots,n
,
$$

with each independent varaible $x_j$ corresponding to a smoothing parameter $\lambda_j$ where $j=1,\cdots,m$. The model is fitted and the paramters estimates including the smoothing parameters estimates ($\hat{\lambda_1},\cdots,\hat{\lambda_m}$) and $\hat{\sigma}$ are found. Now how can we apply these estimates for generating a data similar to the generalized additive model above?

Comment: You can just do the same thing, can't you? Run your GAM and then add some Gaussian noise to each $\hat{y}_i$.

Comment: Could you please say how I can apply $\hat{\lambda}$s exactly?

Comment: If you're in R, use `predict()`. It has a method for outputs from the `gam()` function in the `gam` package. If you're doing it with your own code -- follow the answer below. If that doesn't work update your question with your code and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I found that another simple solution is just to find the prediction `\hat{y_i}` , and then add a Guassian noise to it.

Comment: That's what I meant. Sorry if that wasn't  clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding:  you don't need to use the estimated smoothing parameters when predicting new data.  You simply need to evaluate the basis functions for the new data points.  The penalty terms only come in in the process of choosing the parameters of the basis expansion terms.

So, the model in the univariate case (multivariate is simple generalization) is 
$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1+ \displaystyle\sum_kb_k(x)\gamma_k + \epsilon_{it}
$$

The $\gamma$ are the coefs on the splined terms.

Define $\theta = [\beta, \gamma]$ and $Z = [x, b(x)]$

The model is solved by 
$$
\hat\theta = (Z^TZ+ f(\lambda, b, x))^{-1}Z^Ty
$$
That $f(\lambda, b, x)$ is the smoother matrix.  In the simplest case -- linear splines, it is $\lambda * \text{diag}[0,0, 1, 1, ..., 1]$.

So you get your $\hat\theta$.  If you want to predict, you just need $Z^*$.  You get that by using your basis expansion $b_k(x)$.  The fitted values are $Z^*\hat\theta$.

Here is a simple example in R, with linear splines:

```
#fake training data
N <- 1000
x <- runif(N, 0, 10)
y <- .3*sin(x*2)+rnorm(N)

#basis function
spl <- function(x, knot){
  out <- x
  out[x < knot] <- 0
  out[x >= knot] <- x[x >= knot] - knot
  return(out)
}

#make a design matrix
library(foreach)
Xmat <- foreach(i = seq(.25, 9.75, .25), .combine = cbind) %do% {
  spl(x, i)
}
dmat <- cbind(1, x, Xmat)

#make the diagonal of the smoother matrix
pvec <- c(0,0, rep(1, ncol(Xmat)))

#function to estimate parameters
getBhat <- function(lam){
  Bhat <- solve(crossprod(dmat) + lam*diag(pvec)) %*% t(dmat) %*% y
  return(Bhat)
}

#new data to predict
newx <- seq(5, 10, .1)

#new design matrix
newXmat <- foreach(i = seq(.25, 9.75, .25), .combine = cbind) %do% {
  spl(newx, i)
}
newdmat <- cbind(1, newx, newXmat)

#the results, for various smoothing parameters
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(x, y)
lines(newx, newdmat %*% getBhat(0), col = 'red', lwd = 3) 
plot(x, y)
lines(newx, newdmat %*% getBhat(10), col = 'red', lwd = 3) 
plot(x, y)
lines(newx, newdmat %*% getBhat(100), col = 'red', lwd = 3) 
plot(x, y)
lines(newx, newdmat %*% getBhat(1000), col = 'red', lwd = 3)
```

[image]